# "Es" als Pronomen

Tags: phrase, grammaticality, pronoun

Warum haben wir "können" anstatt " kann" auf dem folgenden Satz? Ist es möglich, "es" durch "sie"  zu ersetzen?

> Die Dauer der Reise bestimmt ihr selbst. Es können einige Wochen oder mehrere Monate sein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das, was [Carsten](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/70176/1487) und [bakunin](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/70177/1487) in ihren Antworten geschrieben haben, nämlich dass das Subjekt die Wortgruppe *»einige Wochen oder mehrere Monate«* ist, ist zwar richtig, beantwortet aber nicht die ausdrücklich gestellten Fragen, ob *»es«* hier als Pronomen fungiert und durch *»sie«* ersetzt werden kann.

---

Diese beiden Formulierungen haben dieselbe Bedeutung:

> 1. es kann sein
> 2. es ist möglich

Daher ist folgender Satz korrekt (die Monate lasse ich weg, die tun nichts zur Sache):

> Einige Wochen sind möglich.

Hier ist auch klar, dass *»einige Wochen«* das Subjekt sind. Und weil das Subjekt im Plural steht, ist auch sonnenklar, dass das auch für das Verb gelten muss. (Statt *ist* ist also *sind* richtig.)

Das müsste man daher eigentlich auch so sagen können:

> Einige Wochen können sein.

Das ist eigentlich auch richtig, aber das Wörtchen *es* ist so fest mit *sein können* verbunden, dass es auch dann als [Expletivum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum) erhalten bleibt, wenn es eigentlich ja schon durch ein konkretes Subjekt ersetzt wurde.

Expletiva sind Füllwörter, die keine echte Bedeutung haben und nur im Satz stehen, um eine Lücke zu füllen. Sie unterscheiden sich unter anderem dadurch von anderen Bestandteilen des Satzes, dass man danach nicht sinnvoll fragen kann:

> Es regnet.

Hier macht es keinen Sinn danach zu fragen wer regnet, denn *»es«* ist nicht der Verursacher des Regens. Noch klarer wird die Funktion des expletiven *»es«* in diesem Beispiel:

> Es fährt ein Zug nach nirgendwo.
> <sub>*(Video des gleichnamigen Schlagers auf [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYnotUA4p1E))*</sub>

Den Satz könnte man auch so schreiben:

> Ein Zug fährt nach nirgendwo.

Wenn man unbedingt alle Satzglieder hinter dem Verb haben will, würde die Position vor dem Verb leer bleiben, was nicht sein kann. Daher verwendet man ein expletives *»es«* an dieser Stelle. Dieses Wort erscheint auf den ersten Blick wie das Subjekt des Satzes, aber wenn man danach fragt (*Wer fährt nach nirgendwo?*) bekommt man nicht dieses Füllwort als Antwort, sondern das tatsächliche Subjekt (*ein Zug*).

Und so ist das auch in diesem Satz:

> **Es** können einige Wochen sein.

Es handelt sich also um ein Expletivum, also um einen Lückenfüller.

Bei *»kann sein«* liegt zudem der bemerkenswerte Fall vor, dass anstelle des Wortes *»es«* auch das Wort *»das«* als Expletivum verwendet werden kann:

> **Das** können einige Wochen sein.

Dass dieses Wort nicht das Subjekt ist, erkennt man daran, dass es ein Einzahlwort ist und somit nicht mit dem Verb übereinstimmt, das in der Mehrzahl vorliegt.

---

Statt *»es«* und *»das«* kann man tatsächlich auch das in der Frage vorgeschlagene Wort *»sie«* verwenden. Wenn man das tut, ändert sich die Situation aber grundlegend: *»Sie«* ist dann kein funktionsloses Expletivum, sondern ein Demonstrativpronomen, das sich auf *»die Reise«* aus den vorangegangenen Satz bezieht. Daher wird es zum Subjekt, und das Verb muss dann auch in der Einzahl stehen:

> Die Dauer der Reise bestimmt ihr selbst. **Sie kann** einige Wochen sein.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank. Es war sehr klar für mich

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort „es“ ist hier nicht das Subjekt, das Subjekt ist „einige Wochen oder mehrere Monate“.

Comment: Deshalb können wir den Satz so verändern? " Einige Wochen oder mehrere Monate können  es sein? Und wie kann man versteht, dass "es" ist platzhalter oder pronomen?

Answer (score 1):

Um zu ergänzen, was @Carsten_S bereits gesagt hat:

Das Subjekt ist in der Tat "einige Wochen oder mehrere Monate". Vergleiche:

> Es können einige Wochen sein.
> Es kann eine Woche sein.

NICHT aber:

> Es kann einige Wochen sein.
> Es können eine Woche sein.

Wie Du siehst, hängt Singular bzw. Plural des Verbs "können" von Singluar oder Plural der (sogenannten "Nominalphrase") "einige Wochen"/"eine Woche" ab.

Answer (score 0):

*Es* ist das Subjekt des Satzes, *einige Wochen oder mehrere Monate* das Prädikativ. Das Verb kongruiert in solchen Fällen (Pronomen im Sg. als Subjekt, Nominalphrase im Pl. als Prädikativ) mit dem Prädikativ und nicht mit dem Subjekt, daher der Plural *können*. *Es* bezieht sich nicht einfach auf *die Dauer der Reise*, sondern auf den im vorangegangen Satz eingeführten Sachverhalt, also dass eine Reisedauer festgelegt werden kann.

Ein ähnliches Beispiel. Das Subjekt *es* bezieht sich auf das Sich-dort-Aufhalten und *nur wenige Minuten* ist das Prädikativ, mit dem das finite Verb *waren* kongruiert.

> Er glaubte, sich stundenlang dort aufgehalten zu haben, doch ein Blick auf die Uhr belehrte in eines Besseren. Es waren nur wenige Minuten gewesen. (aus *Perry Rhodan*)

Ein anderes Beispiel. Hier könnte man auch mit normalem anaphorischem *sie* anstelle von *es* anschließen, aber die Bedeutung wäre nicht genau die gleiche: *sie* würde sich einfach auf *einige Männer* beziehen, während *es* das Heraustreten aus dem Wald mit einschließt. Das Verb kongruiert mit dem Prädikativ *Kurden*.

> Einige Männer traten aus dem Walde. Es waren Kurden. (nach Karl May)

Ein etwas anderes gelagertes Beispiel, in dem *es* sich nicht auf einen Sachverhalt, sondern auf etwas sprachlich nicht explizit Gemachtes bezieht: die verbleibenden Plätze am Vierertisch.

> Es fängt an, als ich mich hier im Speisewagen zu zwei Bier trinkenden, gestriegelten jungen Männern an den Vierertisch setzen will. Es sind die letzten freien Plätze im von schlechter Laune überfüllten Zug von Wien nach Innsbruck. ([bergwelten.com](https://www.bergwelten.com/a/ana-zirner-im-kaukasus-zwischen-den-welten))